# css 3 cube flip transforms - on page transition - using twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-transforms

PROBLEM STATEMENT

I was inspired by the cube flip transforms presented [here](http://desandro.github.com/3dtransforms/docs/cube.html)

I figured it would be great to have such transitions when I redirect the user from one page to another.

Then on inspecting the HTML I found out that it was an effect carried out on stacked divs.

I managed to replicate this at http://jsfiddle.net/celestialcitizen/WpxX3/14/

Now my site is designed with Twitter Bootstrap. So I decided to stack the various pages of my site as divs within a single page. I have a failed attempt up at http://jsfiddle.net/celestialcitizen/Rt4eR/4/

1. Can anyone help me correct it ?
2. When I do these transforms can I still ensure that elements within a page / div are clickable ?

EDIT:

These JS Fiddles must be viewed on safari and Firefox 15.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's late, but I did a little bit of jQuery porting of your first replication:

http://jsfiddle.net/celestialcitizen/WpxX3/14/

And here's the second one:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rt4eR/11/

It looked like you were messing up everything with the `navbar-fixed-top` bootstrap class and with the faces dimensions and positioning.

Notice the `e.preventDefault()` jQuery call, which would invalidate any link behaviour in your faces (i.e. remove it if you need a menu, etc).

Answer (score 0):

this example I did about 3D transform might help, you can inspect the css/js/html for details

http://www.css3rubikexperiment.net/

To answer your quetion:

1. The perspective of your transitions box might be wrong. Theses parameter ara a good start.

   ```
   -webkit-perspective: 800;
   -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 90px;
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-perspective, 1s;
   -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
   ```
2. Yes, yes you can. After all we talking about div containers